# haskell, function composition

Tags: function, haskell, composition

I need some help to solve a task on function composition in Haskell. I need to write a function that given an Integer `n` and a list of inner lists of elements, returns the list of `n-th` element in each inner list. So it would be like:
`select 2 [[2,3,4],[5,6],[9,9,9]] = [3,6,9]`. The thing is, I need to write it using function composition so it should look like `select = ...`. In other words, I want to make this **point-free**.

For now, I have the following:

```
select::Int->[[Int]]->[Int]
select a = map $ head. reverse. take a
```

I'm stuck with it, I don't know how to remove those `a` from the first and only clause. Can anybody help me with this?:)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You will have to give the integer n (guess that is a in your code?), to one of the combined functions.

Comment: So that's what is done by now, I need to remove `a` from the definition.

Comment: Doesn't make it anymore clear what you are trying to accomplish, sorry.

Comment: Try this https://blunt.herokuapp.com/#input=select%20a%20%3D%20map%20%24%20head.%20reverse.%20take%20a%20

Comment: If you are learning, don't try to write a point-free function. Write a normal function with arguments, get it working, then *transform* it to point-free style.

Comment: I guess it's the exercise to write it ;)

Comment: Side note: You give the example: `select 2 [[2,3,4],[5,6],[9,9,9]] = [3,6,9]`, which implies that the first element of the list is at index 1. This is non-standard in Haskell (and most programming languages)—typically lists are indexed starting at 0. To me, this would be the expected behavior: `select 1 [[2,3,4],[5,6],[9,9,9]] = [3,6,9]`.

Comment: @MaxGabriel The task indicated to start at 1. To me, this wouldn't be written point-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you currently have, you can use `select = map . ((head . reverse) .) . take`, you could also simplify this to `select = map . (last .) . take`. An alternative would be to use `select = map . flip (!!) . subtract 1`.

You can use the [`pointfree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) package to derive pointfree versions of functions automatically.

Generally I would advise against this though. Functions that have multiple parameters become quite obfuscated when they are defined in pointfree style.